# Watch YouTube in Browser with Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, video

What is the easiest way to watch YouTube in a web browser when using Raspbian?  I tried using something called PiVid with Chromium, but videos never played (despite it otherwise working as described here:  [Bringing YouTube to Raspberry Pi Browsers](http://blog.pi3g.com/2013/08/bringing-youtube-to-raspberry-pi-browsers/).  I was not able to try Midori due to a problem with ICU (I'm running a custom version).

Do I need to use a certain release date?

Comment: Have you tried `yt` (Raspbian but not browser) or the youtube plugin in xbmc (not Raspbian) ?

Comment: I haven't tried `yt`, but that might be the way to go.  I'm running other software that is already working on Raspbian, so switching to XBMC isn't my preferred solution right now.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I have found is to use Steven Hickson's youtube player, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
git clone git://github.com/StevenHickson/PiAUISuite.git
cd PiAUISuite/Install/
./InstallAUISuite.sh
```

When it runs it will ask if you want to install each part of the suite on by one, just say no to all of them apart from the youtube player

Then go to youtube in your browser and click on a video

Comment: Which browser do you typically use?  It's not working for me in Chromium, but that could be due to a conflict with PiVid.  NetSurf didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You might try installing epiphany-browser (from the standard repositories). I tried it last night and was able to watch videos directly on YouTube, after telling YouTube to use the HTML5 player.

1. Open a terminal window or VT and type

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser
   ```

   (Apt will probably require other packages to install it; accept them.)
2. Use Epiphany Web Browser* to navigate to YouTube's [HTML5 Player](http://www.youtube.com/html5) page.
3. Click the button to choose the HTML5 player to play YouTube videos.
4. Navigate to the [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/) videos of your choice.

Unfortunately some videos may not (yet?) be compatible with the HTML5 player, but you will have to try them to see which ones work.

- Officially, the browser is called "Web," but the latest version in the Raspbian "wheezy" repository (version 3.8.2 as of 2015-01-09) appears in the LXDE "Internet" menu as "Epiphany Web Browser," and you can run it from a terminal window using the command `$ epiphany-browser`