# Youtube on Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B)

Tags: video, performance

I just bought a Raspberry Pi 2 (model B) for my father.

After a few trials, which included:

- installing Ubuntu Mate
- installing Raspbian

I finally converged to plain Ubuntu (14.04), which works pretty well, and is quite fluid.

However, YouTube videos as well as videos played with VLC do not run:

- video is not fluid
- I see just some frame, then black screen / a fixed frame, then again just some frame
- audio follows the same fate :(

I decided to go *at least* for the YouTube videos and give up with VLC video playing.
I found some solutions such as [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13955/watch-youtube-in-browser-with-raspbian) or [this one](http://blog.pi3g.com/2013/08/bringing-youtube-to-raspberry-pi-browsers/), but I did not succeed in making it work properly:

- With the **first solution**, I am not able to retrieve the gIT project
- With the **second solution**, I am not able to install PiVid, since it requires OMXplayer, and when I try to install OMXplayer, it is not found (neither using aptitude nor using apt-get)

Unfortunately, I need it to work, since otherwise my father cannot listen to music in streaming!

Do you have any solution to the problem?

Comment: Why don't you use Raspbian?  I doubt your father would care.

Comment: It was not enough fluid, unfortunately, and I had some problems with the monitor. I do not know why, probably I misconfigured it.

Answer (score 1):

Omxplayer was written specifically for the pi so will not be in stock Ubuntu repositories.

The source is [available here](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer), but if you have a Raspbian image it might be easier to pull a binary out of that and try it; I can't seem to find it in the [actual repo](http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/) but it is installed by default.  There's a shell script wrapper, `/usr/bin/omxplayer`, plus you need `/usr/bin/omxplayer.bin`.

Either way, you will also need the pi specific libraries for the videocore hardware.  You could try installing those by taking `rpi-update` from the Raspbian image and running that; it's also in `/usr/bin` and is a shell script.  I think the only prerequisite is `curl`.

You could also use the method I describe at the end [here under `/opt/vc`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27545/5538).

There are other prerequisite libraries that should be in ubuntu.  You will have to track those down by looking at `ldd /usr/bin/omxplayer.bin` on the running pi.  The stuff shown as `=> not found` needs to be installed.

If you are going to use `omxplayer` for youtube videos, I also recommend **[`yt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whitey)**.